# Dumping puppetdb into MySql or even postgres

Tags: mysql, puppet, puppet-enterprise

For auditing purposes we are required to retain put puppet database for 7 years, how may I routinely dump it into a MySQL database, I might have some flexibility in the choice of databases, postgres or MySql.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Postgres as the backing store for PuppetDB, then you can just use the vanilla postgres tools (like pg_dump) to dump a complete copy of the db, then use psql or pg_restore to put that into a clean postgres database for archival purposes. Repeat as necessary.

PuppetDB also has a built-in "export" command (see [the section in the puppetdb docs on "Exporting and anonymizing data"](https://docs.puppet.com/puppetdb/4.1/anonymization.html#using-the-export-command)). That will dump out all of your current catalogs, facts, and reports into a tarball on disk. If your auditors just care about archival access to the raw data (i.e. it doesn't need to be in a DB for querying or anything), maybe that's sufficient?

PuppetDB doesn't work with MySQL as a backing store. If you want to dump its contents to a MySQL db, I'd recommend using the "export" I mentioned earlier, expanding that tarball, then writing a custom script that imports that data in MySQL.

Comment: Thank you very much, I need the default password for the users: pe-postgres and pe-puppetdb. The command,  /opt/puppetlabs/server/bin/pg_dump   pe-puppetdb -U pe-puppetdb -h localhost -F c > /var/tmp/db.$(date +%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S).dump
Password:
prompts me for a password

Comment: I am now able to do a dump_all and then restore, but having some issues, documented here: http://pastebin.com/2kqH5as6